# continue service working when the application closes

Tags: android, android-service

I have a simple **Service**

```
public class UpdateService extends Service {
   private int seconds;
   final static String MY_ACTION = "MY_ACTION";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    timer.start();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

final CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(86400000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        Util.saveInfo(getApplicationContext(), Util.SECONDS, seconds++);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(MY_ACTION);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

     public void onFinish() { }
  };
}
```

When I close an application service stops working. But showing that the service is running.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**Update** 
I changed CountDownTimer to Thread, but the problem remained

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            Util.saveInfo(getApplicationContext(), Util.SECONDS, seconds++);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**OnStart()**

```
    if(!t1.isAlive())
        t1.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `CountDown Timer`  is working only `foreground` means app is running and not minimized or closed. You have to place a `Thread` in `Service` that executing at particular time of you want.

try this :

```
public class LocalService extends Service
{
    private static Timer timer = new Timer(); 
    private Context ctx;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) 
    {
          return null;
    }

    public void onCreate() 
    {
          super.onCreate();
          ctx = this; 
          startService();
    }

    private void startService()
    {           
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new mainTask(), 0, 5000);
    }

    private class mainTask extends TimerTask
    { 
        public void run() 
        {
            toastHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }    

    public void onDestroy() 
    {
          super.onDestroy();
          Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private final Handler toastHandler = new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    };    
}
```

Comment: I updated my post. By the way, Countdown Timer working when app minimized.

Comment: Yes. But what must I do? How to make working timer in the background?

Comment: stops writing "test" after closing application

Comment: means in log test is not printed and ondestroy is called of service or not.

Comment: test is printed but stoped after closing. onDestroy() is not called

Comment: this code is working for me. how to stop your app. put your code.

Comment: are you kill your app then it will automatically stopped by android on  many devices but this code is working my side when you kill your app like this. Killing app stopped all services and receivers.

Comment: And how then working antivirus? In opening apps I see "No recent app" but antivirus is working.

Comment: this is exactly code i'm tried this in new project.

Comment: post your full code how u use this method. I wanna see.